# What happens to vDS networking when my vCenter server crashes

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter, vmware-server

I have a query
What exactly happens when the vCenter server crashes.
I know that the database and logs would be lost if the vCenter Server crashes, but I need to know what will happen to the Guest VMs which are connected via vDS, will they be available on the network and for how long.

Also where are the settings for vDS saved.

The Guest VMs are always available when the vCenter server goes for a reboot(45 mins reboot cycle).

Thanks all in advance

Answer (score 2):

See:
 http://www.yellow-bricks.com/2012/02/08/distributed-vswitches-and-vcenter-outage-whats-the-deal/

Network connectivity during a vCenter outage is preserved. The ability to modify the vDS settings is impaired, but the VMs will maintain connectivity.